# error ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, numpy

my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# OFDM Parameters
subcarriers = 32  # subcarriers
blockSC = 16  # number of subcarriers blocks
data_length = subcarriers * blockSC  # length of data
M = 4  # modulation index
cyclic_prefix = 8  # number of cyclic prefix 
lent = blockSC + cyclic_prefix

# Input Data at Transmitter
data_input = np.random.randint(0, M, size=data_length)

# OFDM TRANSMITTER
# QAM Modulator
qam_sig = np.sqrt(2)/2 * (1 - 2 * data_input) + 1j * np.sqrt(2)/2 * (1 - 2 * np.mod(data_input+1, M))

# Serial to Parallel Converter
parl = np.reshape(qam_sig, (subcarriers, blockSC), order='F')  # Fortran-style ordering
parl_mag = np.fft.fftshift(parl, axes=0)

# IFFT
parl_ifft = np.fft.ifft(parl_mag, axis=0)

# Add Cyclic Prefix
prefixed = np.concatenate((parl_ifft[(subcarriers-cyclic_prefix):subcarriers, :], parl_ifft), axis=0)

# Multipath Fading Channel
path_loss = 10e-9 #asumsi
channel = prefixed * np.sqrt(1 - path_loss) + np.sqrt(path_loss) * np.random.randn(np.size(prefixed))
channel = np.reshape(channel, np.shape(prefixed)) # add this line to reshape channel

# OFDM RECEIVER
# Serial to Parallel Converter
rx = np.reshape(channel, (blockSC + cyclic_prefix, subcarriers)).T

# Remove Cyclic Prefix
unprefixed = rx[:, cyclic_prefix:blockSC+cyclic_prefix]

# FFT
rx_fft_parl = np.fft.fft(unprefixed, axis=0)
rx_fft_mag = np.fft.fftshift(rx_fft_parl, axes=0)

# Parallel to Serial Converter
rx_fft = np.reshape(rx_fft_parl, (1, data_length))
rx_fft_mag_full = np.reshape(rx_fft_mag, (1, data_length))

# QAM Demodulator
data_output = np.round((np.real(rx_fft) - np.sqrt(2)/2) / np.sqrt(2) * (-1) + 1j * (np.imag(rx_fft) - np.sqrt(2)/2) / np.sqrt(2) * (-1)).flatten()

# Symbol Error Checker
data_check = data_input - data_output
data_check[data_check != 0] = 1
symbol_error = (np.sum(data_check) / data_length) * 100
print('Symbol Error Rate is', symbol_error, '%')
```

and i got this error :

> line 32, in 
> channel = prefixed * np.sqrt(1 - path_loss) + np.sqrt(path_loss) * np.random.randn(np.size(prefixed))
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (40,16) (640,)

so what should i do?

i already used another function but still got this

Comment: When you develop code you should be able to deduce (and verify) the shape of each array, and understand how they work (`broadcast`) together.  The problem line has several operators that could be raising this error (the '*' and the '+').  What are you trying to do here?  What's the shape of `prefixed` and `path_loss`?